# Gitlab CE git clone not works via ssh

Tags: git, docker, ssh, gitlab-ce

I had Installed gitlab ce in docker.
I want to make git clone from server via ssh.
I set port 3000 in gitlab config.
When i try to make git clone i had next:

`git clone ssh://git@git.site.com:3000/pm/site-crm.git
Cloning into 'site-crm'...
ssh: connect to host git.site.com port 3000: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

What else i have to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the SSH port forwarding described in [docker-gitlab issue 38](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/issues/38#issuecomment-39640106) is still valid:

> Forward some other port on the host to port 22 of the container and use the `GITLAB_SHELL_SSH_PORT` configuration option to specify the forwarded port to the gitlab application so that the clone urls reflect this.
>
> For example, add `-p 3000:22 -e "GITLAB_SHELL_SSH_PORT=3000"` to the `docker run` command.
> Now you will notice that the ssh clone urls in the gitlab server will change to the form `ssh://git@git.local.host:3000/docker/docker-gitlab.git`.

This is still mentioned in this [2017 blog post](https://blog.xiaket.org/2017/exposing.ssh.port.in.dockerized.gitlab-ce.html), which described another approach.

Comment: Sorry, how can I restart docker container with these params?

Comment: @ВладиславКарпенко stop and remove your current GitLab-CE container, and launch it again, with those additional parameters described in the answer.

Comment: I am using Plesk with the Docker extension. The internal port 22 was being forwarded to port 49155 in the Plesk interface. I first tried adding the environment variable as indicated here in the area that the Plesk interface designates for environment variables, but restarting the container didn't fix it. Maybe I had to remove and recreate the container for the env variable to be picked up. In any case I removed the environment variable and set the option in `gitlab.rb`: `gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 49155`. Then I restarted the container and voilà, links now have the form as above

Comment: @JohnRDOrazio OK. Thank you for this feedback.